# deleting file through CMD

Tags: cmd.exe

I am trying to delete files through

```
forfiles -p "E:\check" -s -m *.* -d -10 -c "cmd /c del /Q /S E:\check"
```

But if there is a file that is more than 10 days old, it removes all files in the folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### If there is a file that is more than 10 days old, it removes all files in the folder.

```
forfiles -p "E:\check" -s -m *.* -d -10 -c "cmd /c del /Q /S E:\check"
```

That is hardly surprising when you are deleting the directory you are searching (and all of its sub-directories) with the following command:

```
del /Q /S E:\check
```

Instead you need to delete the matching files. Try the following command:

```
forfiles -p "E:\check" -s -m *.* -d -10 -c "cmd /c del /q @path"
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [del](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html) - Delete one or more files.
- [delolder](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-delolder.html) - Delete files older than N days
- [forfiles](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) - Select a file (or set of files) and execute a command on each file. Batch processing.